# Can a CouchDB document update handler get an update conflict?

Tags: erlang, couchdb

**How likely is a revision conflict when using an update handler?** Should I concern myself with conflict-handling code when writing a robust update function?

As described in [Document Update Handlers](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers), CouchDB 0.10 and later allows on-demand server-side document modification.

Update handlers can process non-JSON formats; but the other major features are these:

- An HTTP front-end to arbitrarily complex document modification code
- Similar code needn't be written for all possible clients—a DRY architecture
- *Execution is faster and less likely to hit a revision conflict*

I am unclear about the third point. Executing locally, the update handler will run much faster and with lower latency. But in situations with high contention, that does not guarantee a successful update. *Or does the update handler guarantee a successful update?*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update conflicts are still possible when using update handlers.**

Due to the reduced "round-trip time," the chance of an update conflict is lower
but not zero. A conflict will feel normal: a 409 response code
with this JSON:

```
{"error":"conflict","reason":"Document update conflict."}
```

I successfully triggered a conflict using the [document update handler example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972068/couchdb-document-update-handlers-in-place-updates/2979647#2979647),
and running curl twice in short succession in the shell.

```
curl -v -X PUT \
http://localhost:5984/db/_design/app/_update/accumulate/my_doc?amount=10 \
& curl -X PUT \
  http://localhost:5984/db/_design/app/_update/accumulate/my_doc?amount=1
```

One of the curl responses (randomly) was a 201 and the other a 409.

### Document update handlers do not fundamentally change CouchDB

Updates are subject to conflicts, as well as validation failures (`401 Unauthorized`,
`403 Forbidden`, etc.)

Comment: Its even easier: Use replication, one of the main features of CouchDB and you can easily run into a conflict.