# couchdb/cloudant update handler not working as expected

Tags: javascript, couchdb, cloudant, couchapp

I am developing an app that uses Cloudant as the database. I have a situation where I make two database calls at almost the time to the same document, but, because of it, I get a conflict error. So I tried to create an update handler function in a cloudant database that looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": "_design/_updateHandler",
  "updates": {
    "in-place": "function(doc, req) {
        var field = req.body.field,
        var value= req.body.value,
        var doc[field] = value;
        return [doc, toJSON(doc)];
    }"
  }
}
```

And it adds  a field in the document, but it doesn't update an existing field of it. Is it the expected behavior? It doesn't look like so in the [cloudant documentation for update handlers](https://docs.cloudant.com/design_documents.html#update-handlers) nor in the [couchdb documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers).

If not, how can I fix this problem so it does update an existing field?
Also, as answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983220/can-a-couchdb-document-update-handler-get-an-update-conflict), an update handler function would still get an update conflict, but how can I avoid it?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I advise you to you an advisory lock mechanism; or retry on conflict.

For advisory lock; you can simple use a memcache/redis; or in memory dictionary; or a lock document in cloudant.

For retry on conflich method; just re-apply your changes on conflict error (http 409).

Comment: The example code you pasted has lots of bugs... commas after var statements, `var doc` when doc is already defined, etc. :( Do you have newer code? or code closer to what you're attempting? You might test the function on it's own in your browsers console to get the JS cleaned up first.

Comment: Also, the example in the CouchDB Docs is easier to iterate from than the one(s) in the wiki: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/ddocs.html#update-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example of a CouchDB and Cloudant compatible Update Function to do what you're after--update a single field.

```
function(doc, req) {
  if (!doc) doc = {_id: req.uuid};
  var body = JSON.parse(req.body);
  var field = body.field;
  var value = body.value;
  doc[field] = value;
  return [doc, JSON.stringify(doc)];
}
```

The body of the `POST` request is considered to be valid JSON, so you may want to do some header checks for `application/json`.

Additionally, if you only plan to do field = value stuff like you have here, then `application/x-www-form-url-encoded` would be better as it will lower your payload size and parsing time--CouchDB and Cloudant will auto-parse that media type into the `req.form` object.

Lastly, it's best to never prefix anything you give to CouchDB or Cloudant with an underscore as its considered a reserved character at the beginning of top level fields and `_id` values. The `_design/_updateHandler` name is (subsequently) very confusing...

Here's the JSON to copy/paste into your database to get a working update function to do what you wanted:

```
{
    "_id": "_design/overwrite",
    "updates": {
        "in-place": "function(doc, req) {\n  if (!doc) doc = {_id: req.uuid};\n  var body = JSON.parse(req.body);\n  var field = body.field;\n  var value = body.value;\n  doc[field] = value;\n  doc.body = body;\n  return [doc, JSON.stringify(doc)];\n}"
    }
}
```

To update an existing doc you'd make an HTTP request like this one (where `bigbluehat` is the previously stored document's _id:

```
POST /db/_design/overwrite/_update/in-place/bigbluehat
Content-Type: application/json

{"field": "name", "value": "BigBlueHat"}
```

Or, if you don't include the document `_id` in the request URL, you'll get a new document which uses the `req.uuid` value to store a new document.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the code bugs! I got frustrated because of conflicts and ended up with this code, where nothing happened. I still have problems with the best way to resolve conflicts. Right now I'm using Safak Ulusoy's solution, but it doesn't feel right. Is there a better way to resolve it?

Comment: Forgot to mention... Very useful tips as well!

Comment: Conflicts aren't necessarily bad. :) It just depends on why they're happening, whether you can architect around (or for!) them, and what the root cause of it is--overly frequent updates to a single doc which should actually be being stored in several docs? (mis)using CouchDB for something Redis is better at (in-memory counting)? etc. Maybe post another question and ping me. ^_^