# Change notification in CouchDB when a field is set

Tags: couchdb

I'm trying to get notifications in a CouchDB change poll as soon as pre-defined field is set or changed. I've already had a look at filters that can be used for filtering change events(`db/_changes?filter=myfilter`). However, I've not yet found a way to include this temporal information, because you can only get the current version of the document in this filter functions.

Is there any possibility to create such a filter?

If it does not work, I could export my field to a separate database and the only poll for changes in that db, but I'd prefer to keep together my data for obvious reasons.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What "temporal information" do you want to include? How does the temporal information relate to the document revisions?

Comment: Well, temporal information is just the old state of the field, so I can check whether it has been changed or not. Perhaps there are sophisticated workarounds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct: filters and `_changes` feeds can only see snapshots of a document. What you need is *a function which can see the old document and the new document* and act correctly. But that is unavailable in `_filters` and `_changes`.

Obviously your client code knows if it updates that field. You might update your client code however there is a better solution.

**Update functions can access both documents.** I suggest you make an _update
function which notices the field change and flags that in the document. Next you
have a simple filter checking for that flag. The best part is, you can use a
rewrite function to make the HTTP API exactly the same as before.

### 1. Create an update function to flag interesting updates

Your `_design/myapp` would be `{"updates", "smart_updater": "(see below)"}`.
Update functions are very flexible (see my recent [update handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972068/couchdb-document-update-handlers-in-place-updates/2979647#2979647)
walkthrough). However we only want to mimic the normal HTTP/JSON API.

Your `updates.smart_updater` field would look like this:

```
function (doc, req) {
    var INTERESTING = 'dollars'; // Set me to the interesting field.

    var newDoc = JSON.parse(req.body);
    if(newDoc.hasOwnProperty(INTERESTING)) {
        // dollars was set (which includes 0, false, null, undefined
        // values. You might test for newDoc[INTERESTING] if those
        // values should not trigger this code.
        if((doc === null) || (doc[INTERESTING] !== newDoc[INTERESTING])) {
            // The field changed or created!
            newDoc.i_was_changed = true;
        }
    }

    if(!newDoc._id) {
        // A UUID generator would be better here.
        newDoc._id = req.id || Math.random().toString();
    }

    // Return the same JSON the vanilla Couch API does.
    return [newDoc, {json: {'id': newDoc._id}}];
}
```

Now you can PUT or POST to `/db/_design/myapp/_update/[doc_id]` and it will feel
just like the normal API except *if you update the dollars field, it will add
an additional flag*, `i_was_changed`. That is how you will find this change
later.

### 2. Filter for documents with the changed field

This is very straightforward:

```
function(doc, req) {
    return doc.i_was_changed;
}
```

Now you can query the `_changes` feed with a `?filter=` parameter. (Replication
also supports this filter, so you could pull to your local system all documents
which most recently changed/created the field.

That is the basic idea. The remaining steps will make your life easier if you
already have lots of client code and do not want to change the URLs.

### 3. Use rewriting to keep the HTTP API the same

This is available in CouchDB 0.11, and the best resource is Jan's blog post,
[nice URLs in CouchDB](http://blog.couch.io/post/443028592/whats-new-in-apache-couchdb-0-11-part-one-nice-urls).

Briefly, you want a vhost which sends all traffic to your rewriter (which itself
is a flexible "bouncer" to all design doc functionality based on the URL).

```
curl -X PUT http://example.com:5984/_config/vhosts/example.com \
  -d '"/db/_design/myapp/_rewrite"'
```

Then you want a `rewrites` field in your design doc, something like (not
tested)

```
[
    {
        "comment": "Updates should go through the update function",
        "method": "PUT",
        "from": "db/*",
        "to"  : "db/_design/myapp/_update/*"
    },
    {
        "comment": "Creates should go through the update function",
        "method": "POST",
        "from": "db/*",
        "to"  : "db/_design/myapp/_update/*"
    },
    {
        "comment": "Everything else is just like normal",
        "from": "*",
        "to"  : "../../../*"
    }
]
```

(Once again, I got this code from examples and existing code I have laying
around but it's not 100% debugged. However I think it makes the idea very clear.
Also remember this step is optional however the advantage is, you never have to
change your client code.)

Comment: Yeah, never heard about update handlers before. This will do the trick. Thank you very much!