# Couch DB bulk update using handlers

Tags: json, nosql, couchdb

I'm using CouchDB and I have a situation where there are a bunch of documents keyed on user ids. I would like to be able to send a single query to update a particular field in all these documents. For example when a notification comes in, I'd like each user document to be updated with it by passing in the list of users to whom the notification applies and the notification message.

Answer (score 8):

Sadly the _update handlers in CouchDB currently only support a single document at a time, so it's not possible to use an _update handler on multiple documents. For this, you'd need to build a small "proxy," server-side script that would receive the request and send individual _update handler requests one per document. Not ideal, but until there's a patch to allow bulk update handlers to be built, this is the way to go.

I've requested a _bulk_update handler (or similar) be added to a future version of CouchDB...as I'd like the feature as well. :)
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1303

Answer (score 3):

I'd read `_changes` (probably [apply a filter](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/notifications.html#filters)) and then execute the HTTP queries needed.

Keep in mind that you'll need to fetch the document, before updating it.

Comment: Well I saw this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972068/couchdb-document-update-handlers-in-place-updates on how to use update handlers, it seems like it should be possible to setup a script on the server to do the work, which would avoid passing the documents back and forth.