# Couchdb update handlers

Tags: couchdb, handlers

Following: [CouchDB Document Update Handlers (in-place updates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972068/couchdb-document-update-handlers-in-place-updates) and http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers

I'm trying to create my own function which increment an integer for now, but I'm getting:

**{"error":"bad_request","reason":"Attachment name can't start with '_'"}**

My design document looks like: _design/db

```
  "check": {
        "increment": "function(doc,req){ var channel = req.query.channel; doc.channels[0].sp = doc.channels[0].sp+1;  return[channel, 'check']}"
    }
```

And the request is like:

```
curl -X PUT https://server/db/_design/db/_check/increment/channels?channel=foo
```

I don't understand very well what I'm doing wrong, if I remove the '_' I will get:

**{"error":"conflict","reason":"Document update conflict."}**

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your request is wrong, I think. Try something like this:

```
curl -X PUT https://server/db/_design/db/_update/increment/channels?channel=foo
```

Second, your update handler function should be in an "updates" key directly in the design document (so not as part of any view). So your design document should look like this:

```
{
    "_id": "_design/doc",
    "updates": {
        "increment": "function(doc,req){ var channel = req.query.channel; doc.channels[0].sp = doc.channels[0].sp+1;  return[channel, 'check']}"
    }
}
```