# CouchDB Update Handler Won't Add Correctly

Tags: couchdb, handler

First of all I have read [CouchDB Document Update Handlers (in-place updates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972068/couchdb-document-update-handlers-in-place-updates) and have adopted the code in the answer to that question.

I have an update handler that takes a query string amount and is supposed to add that to doc.count of a given document. Instead of adding the two amounts, it merely lists them. E.G. 5+5=55. 
Also adding a parseInt() to doc.count yields an error message:

```
{"error":"render_error","reason":"undefined response from update function"}
```

My update handler is:

"countPlus": "function(doc, req) {var amount1 = doc.count; var amount2 = parseInt(req.query.amount); doc.count = amount1 + amount2; return [doc, doc.count]; }"

The js that handles the requests is:

```
if (count != null && count != NaN && count != 0) {
    var currentCounter = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    url: $(location).attr("href").replace("_show/action", "_update/countPlus") + "?amount=" + count,
    contentType : "application/json",         
    dataType: "json"
          });
var currentCountResponse = currentCounter.responseText;
        alert(currentCountResponse);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your response seems to be an integer. Maybe you should try to "stringify" it.