# Update single field in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

I want update one field in a document. I created a new document:

[image: My new document]

And I would like to change the value of field `name` from `aaa` to `test`. I copied a script from: `wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers`, and I created a new design document:

[image: New design document]

Next I created a URL:

```
localhost:5984/asd/_design/temp/_update/in-place-query/8d6257096bbb199a3757954c00000d0c?name=title&value=test
```

That should update my field. I instead saw the error:

```
"{"error":"TypeError","reason":"{[{<<\"message\">>,<<\"point is undefined\">>},\n  {<<\"fileName\">>,<<\"../share/couchdb/server/main.js\">>},\n  {<<\"lineNumber\">>,1500},\n  {<<\"stack\">>,\n   <<\"(\\\"_design/temp\\\",[object Array],[object Array])@../share/couchdb/server/main.js:1500\\n()@../share/couchdb/server/main.js:1562\\n@../share/couchdb/server/main.js:1573\\n\">>}]}"}"
```

Have you got any idea to repair it?

Answer (score 1):

Your update handler design doc should be in the form:

```
{
    "_id": "_design/app",
    "updates": {
        "accumulate": "function (doc, req) { // Your code here }"
    }
}
```

For further information, please checkout this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2979647/2244476) post.

Let me know if this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Document updates require that you send the `_rev` id which means that you must have read the document prior. So, all you do is set the value of whatever document object property then pass the pre-read document back to couch in a PUT w `_rev` for updating.